# How to filter a large geojson file in R

Tags: r, json, geojson, r-highcharter

I'm having issues filtering a large geojson file with R. If I just want to show the map for one country, I don't want the entire map of europe to be loaded which is huge. So I want to filter this dataset for example for Bulgaria -- `CNTR_CODE == "BG"` but I can't manage.
Please find code to download below and an initial effort which doesn't result in the desired outcome

```
link <- 'https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/GISCO/distribution/v2/nuts/download/ref-nuts-2013-01m.geojson.zip'
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(link,temp)
mapdata <- readLines(unzip(temp, "NUTS_RG_01M_2013_4326_LEVL_3.geojson"))
mapdata <- jsonlite::fromJSON(mapdata, simplifyVector = FALSE)
#glimpse(mapdata)
mapdata$features[[100]]$properties$CNTR_CODE
[1] "BG"


  library(sf)
  mapdata2 <- copy(mapdata)
  mapdata2 %>% 
    filter(CNTR_CODE %in% c('BG'))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list, then `Filter` could work:

```
path = "NUTS_RG_01M_2013_4326_LEVL_3.geojson"
x <- jsonlite::fromJSON(path, simplifyVector = FALSE)
x$features <- Filter(function(z) z$properties$CNTR_CODE == "BG", x$features)
vapply(x$features, function(x) x$properties$CNTR_CODE, "")
```

If you want to keep the data in geojson character format, you could use [jqr](https://github.com/ropensci/jqr)

```
path = "NUTS_RG_01M_2013_4326_LEVL_3.geojson"
x <- paste0(readLines(path), collapse = "")
xx <- jqr::jq(x, '.features |= map(select(.properties.CNTR_CODE == "BG"))')
jqr::jq(xx, '.features[].properties.CNTR_CODE')
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not such a large file if you use the right tools.

1. `library(geojsonsf)` can read the geojson directly to an `sf` object
2. `library(mapdeck)` can plot all the polygons

```
link <- 'https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/GISCO/distribution/v2/nuts/download/ref-nuts-2013-01m.geojson.zip'
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(link,temp)

library(geojsonsf)
library(sf)

sf <- geojsonsf::geojson_sf(unzip(temp, "NUTS_RG_01M_2013_4326_LEVL_3.geojson"))
```

Then you can filter the `sf` object and plot

```
library(mapdeck)
set_token( "YOUR_MAPBOX_API_TOKEN" )

mapdeck(
    style = mapdeck_style("dark")
) %>%
    add_polygon(
        data = sf[ sf$CNTR_CODE %in% c("BG"), ]
        , fill_colour = "NUTS_NAME"
        , legend = T
    )
```

[image]

Or plot the whole lot

```
mapdeck(
    style = mapdeck_style("dark")
) %>%
    add_polygon(
        data = sf
        , fill_colour = "NUTS_NAME"
        , legend = T
    )
```

[image]